# Finding a limit of a rational function

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 27} \frac{x^{1/3} - 3}{x - 27}$.

Hello,

I am stuck on this one. I am sure there is a simple step but I am not seeing it. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Notice that $$(x^{\frac 1n})^n=x$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hint:

$$(x-27)=(x^{\frac{1}{3}}-3)(x^{\frac{2}{3}}+3x^{\frac{1}{3}}+9)$$

Comment: ahhh thank you so much!

Comment: how would you figure out how to factor that? just practice?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

This is equivalent to

$$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{x-3}{x^3-27}$$

A simpler ratio.  Factor from here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. For any differentiable function near $a$, one has
$$
\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(a).
$$ Then just apply it to $f(x)=x^{1/3}-3,\, a=27$.